# When to include or reject interaction term in two variable linear regression

Tags: regression, correlation, interaction, f-statistic

I am studying a treatment that degrades device quality and performed an independent sample test on two batches that had different initial quality. I analyzed the data with a two variable linear regression, the details are in my previous question here: [How to combine 2 unpaired t tests that test the same effect](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162918/how-to-combine-2-unpaired-t-tests-that-test-the-same-effect)

My specific questions in bold at the bottom of the post after this background information.

For easy reference the output of the regression is here:

[image]

It is very reasonable to assume that that the initial quality of the device batch could determine the size of the effect of the treatment.  For this reason I also tried including a interaction term in the regression.

[image]

When I am presenting my data I am reporting the model with no interaction term.  **My justification for this is:**

**1)**  Including the interaction term results in a reduced F-statistic for the regression.

**2)**  Considering the regression $\beta$s individually I see:

**a.)** The interaction term has a p-value of 0.91, which suggests it
    adds no value to the model.

**b.)** The p-value for the Quality and Treatment parameters increased significantly, particularly for the Treatment parameter, which is the interesting effect.

**Therefore I'm wondering:**

**1)**  Have I made a reasonable decision to exclude the interaction term?

**2)**  Are my justifications sufficient or could anything additional be considered / mentioned?

**3)**  How is it that inclusion of the interaction term (which has almost zero predictive power according to it's p-value) can dilute the information contained in the individual parameters (as indicated by their individual p-value increases)

Comment: That's an *interaction* term, not a correlation term.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  I changed it to "interaction term" everywhere.  BTW, does a significant interaction term imply correlation in the variables?